# ¿Como cerrar sesión después de un tiempo de inactividad?

Tags: php, html

Estoy empezando a trabajar en web y me surge un problema.

En primera, no se bien como funciona un script en php, es decir no se si se ejecuta infinitamente, pues quiero hacer un script que me calcule el tiempo de sesión de un usuario dentro de una pagina y que después de cierto tiempo de inactividad, se termine la sesión y mande a la pagina de login.

El problema yace que no tengo claro como debe ser el script ni tampoco donde lo debo llamar para que este revise todo el tiempo si hay inactividad del usuario.

Comment: Esta pregunta en SO ingles te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php

Answer (score 9):

Se podría realizar , al momento de crear la `SESSION` , guardar el tiempo en una variable de `SESSIÓN` este se obtiene haciendo uso de la función [time](http://php.net/manual/es/function.time.php) *(en segundos)* para luego comparar con el tiempo que se desee `(Tiempo Actual - valorGuardado) > tiempoenSegundos` para este ejemplo serán *2 minutos*

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['tiempo'])) {
    $_SESSION['tiempo']=time();
}
else if (time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'] > 120) {
    session_destroy();
    /* Aquí redireccionas a la url especifica */
    header("Location: urlLogin");
    die();  
}
$_SESSION['tiempo']=time(); //Si hay actividad seteamos el valor al tiempo actual
```

La solución anterior , funcionará pero falla en un detalle y es que cuando haya actividad la variable de sessión guardada no se actualizará por lo que siempre terminará en el tiempo indicado *(2minutos)* sin o con actividad. Para esto tendríamos que actualizar nuestra variable sesión fuera de todo. Gracias a @Luis AlfredoSerranoDíaz por el detalle

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta, este campo "$_SESSION['tiempo']" a que hace referencia, o cómo es que le indicas tiempo en los corchetes?

Comment: No. Lo que está dentro de los corchetes es la clave para acceder a su valor. Que es asignado con `$_SESSION['tiempo']=time();`

Comment: Segun leo en este codigo no cierra sesion por inactvidad, solo das un tiempo de expiracion a la sesion estes inactivo o no. No soy experto en php pero es lo que entiendo.

Answer (score 5):

creo que en el ejemplo de D.Bulten falta actualizar la sesion en caso de no caducar:

```
//Comprobamos si esta definida la sesión 'tiempo'.
if(isset($_SESSION['tiempo']) ) {

    //Tiempo en segundos para dar vida a la sesión.
    $inactivo = 1200;//20min en este caso.

    //Calculamos tiempo de vida inactivo.
    $vida_session = time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'];

        //Compraración para redirigir página, si la vida de sesión sea mayor a el tiempo insertado en inactivo.
        if($vida_session > $inactivo)
        {
            //Removemos sesión.
            session_unset();
            //Destruimos sesión.
            session_destroy();              
            //Redirigimos pagina.
            header("Location: tupagina");

            exit();
        } else {  // si no ha caducado la sesion, actualizamos
            $_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();
        }


} else {
    //Activamos sesion tiempo.
    $_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();
}
```

o tambien, podemos omitir el ultimo else y actualizar siempre la sesion, ya que si ha caducado redirigimos a "tupagina":

```
    //Comprobamos si esta definida la sesión 'tiempo'.
    if(isset($_SESSION['tiempo']) ) {

        //Tiempo en segundos para dar vida a la sesión.
        $inactivo = 1200;//20min en este caso.

        //Calculamos tiempo de vida inactivo.
        $vida_session = time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'];

            //Compraración para redirigir página, si la vida de sesión sea mayor a el tiempo insertado en inactivo.
            if($vida_session > $inactivo)
            {
                //Removemos sesión.
                session_unset();
                //Destruimos sesión.
                session_destroy();              
                //Redirigimos pagina.
                header("Location: tupagina");

                exit();
            }

    }
    $_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, se me olvido en mi respuesta, buen detalle +1. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un ejemplo más.

```
//Comprobamos si esta definida la sesión 'tiempo'.
if(isset($_SESSION['tiempo']) ) {

    //Tiempo en segundos para dar vida a la sesión.
    $inactivo = 1200;//20min en este caso.

    //Calculamos tiempo de vida inactivo.
    $vida_session = time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'];

        //Compraración para redirigir página, si la vida de sesión sea mayor a el tiempo insertado en inactivo.
        if($vida_session > $inactivo)
        {
            //Removemos sesión.
            session_unset();
            //Destruimos sesión.
            session_destroy();              
            //Redirigimos pagina.
            header("Location: tupagina");

            exit();
        }
} else {
    //Activamos sesion tiempo.
    $_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();
}
```

Comment: Me funciona bien, pero me cierra la sesion despues de los 10 minutos que lo definí aunque el usuario interacua con la pagina, lo que pasa es que no se refresca, solo es un javascript el que me cambia las diferentes secciones, considero que es por eso ya que si pasan los 10 minutos y recargo la pagina, se me cierra la sesion aunque el usuario haya navegado por diferentes secciones. alguna idea para resolver esto?

Comment: Hola @albertoRojas, deberías abrir una pregunta nueva, explicando tu problema, con la parte del código donde te lanza el error. Sin código es casi imposible ver donde podrías tener conflicto y como tienes creado el JS. Tengo el mismo código implementado en mi web y funciona muy bien. También hay que tener en cuenta si por ejemplo tienes varias páginas con sesiones, debes incluir el código en cada página.

Answer (score 1):

Eso es mejor hacerlo con javascript, no entiendo por que la insistencia en crear este tipo de script en php... aqui les dejo el codigo.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function e(q) {
    document.body.appendChild( document.createTextNode(q) );
    document.body.appendChild( document.createElement("BR") );
}
function inactividad() {
    e("Inactivo!!");
}
var t=null;
function contadorInactividad() {
    t=setTimeout("inactividad()",3000);
}
window.onblur=window.onmousemove=function() {
    if(t) clearTimeout(t);
    contadorInactividad();
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la ventaja de hacerlo con javascript? ¿Que pasa si el cliente tiene deshabilitado javascript en el navegador?

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con esta solución si abro la consola de JavaScript y ejecuto `clearTimeout(t)`?

Comment: Sencillo, es casi obsoleto el deshabilitar javascript en el navegador, ya casi nadie hace eso y por qué en javascript y no en PHP, es básico ya que necesitarás de un lenguaje que se ejecute en modo presencial y en secuencia o lo que llamamos constancia... PHP es un lenguaje de interpretación a escala primaria, es decir lograrás muchas cosas con PHP si ejecutas todo mediante un script de opción load es decir al cargar la página pero no te llevará un proceso simultáneo en todo el tiempo de actividad web. Deberías consultar un poco del teme te darás cuenta de que es lo más recomendable.

Comment: El problema de hacerlo en javascript (al menos en este ejemplo)  radica en que no funciona en caso de refrescar la URL. En el ejemplo si refresco la URL a los 2999,  se reinicia el contador y puedo mantener la sesion. Aparte no todo es web en esta vida, las API test o webservices pueden requerir cierres de sesión (aunque incumplan ciertas normas de defunción) y se requiere PHP para ello

Comment: Creo que es un error cerrar sesión desde el front, por seguridad debe ser desde el servidor, ya que si lo haces desde javascript en el lado del cliente este podrá manipular la sesión y el objetivo de poner una sección que caduque es, o darle al usuario un tiempo limitado en una sesión, o por seguridad, por si al usuario se le olvida abierta su sesión, y cuando no se hace desde el servidor se correrían muchos riesgos.